# Printing of Circular Queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm trying to get the output of this program correctly, but I'm not able to. This is because I'm not able to input any string in the insert() function after the line *"printf("Enter the string to be inserted = \n");"* although I am using gets() with proper header file.
The output I'm getting is something like this:

```
Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
1
Enter the string to be inserted =  
Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
1
Enter the string to be inserted =  
Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
1
Enter the string to be inserted =  
Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
3
The contents of the queue are 



Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
2
Deleted string is =

Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
3
The contents of the queue are 


Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
2
Deleted string is =

Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
3
The contents of the queue are 

Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
2
Deleted string is =

Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
3
Queue is empty 
Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue 
Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue 
Choice 3 : Display 
Any other choice : Exit 
Enter your choice
4
```

The program I've written is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 5

int front = 0;
int rear = -1;
char queue_array[MAX][30];

void insert();
void Delete();
void display();

int main()
{
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choice 1 : Enter element into Queue\n");
        printf("Choice 2 : Delete element from Queue\n");
        printf("Choice 3 : Display\n");
        printf("Any other choice : Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: insert();
                    break;
            case 2: Delete();
                    break;
            case 3: display();
                    break;
            default:exit(0);
        } // End of switch()
    } // End of while()
} // End of main()

void insert()
{
    char add_item[30];
    if((front == 0 && rear == MAX - 1) || (front != 0 && rear == front - 1))
        printf("Queue is full\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the string to be inserted = \n");
        gets(add_item);
        if(rear == MAX - 1 && front != 0)
        {
            rear = 0;
            strcpy(queue_array[rear], add_item);
        }
        else
        {
            rear = rear + 1;
            strcpy(queue_array[rear], add_item);
        }
    }
}

void Delete()
{
    char del_item[30];
    if(front == 0 && rear == -1)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    if(front == rear)
    {
        strcpy(del_item, queue_array[front]);
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
    }
    else if(front == MAX - 1)
    {
        strcpy(del_item, queue_array[front]);
        front = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        front = front + 1;
        strcpy(del_item, queue_array[front]);
    }
    printf("Deleted string is =\n");
    puts(del_item);
} // End of delete()

void display()
{
    int i, j;
    if(front == 0 && rear == -1)
    {    
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("The contents of the queue are ");
    if(front > rear)
    {
        for(i = 0; i <= rear; i++)
            puts(queue_array[i]);
        for(j = front; j < MAX - 1; j++)
            puts(queue_array[j]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = front; i <= rear; i++)
            puts(queue_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} // End of display()
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Some char remains in the stdin buffer after your input (scanf does not read newline char), either flush the stdin buffer `fflush(stdin)`or use `scanf("%s", add_item)`

Also I might add that `gets` is prone to buffer overflow problems you are much better off using `fgets`

Comment: Thanks, man! replacing gets with scanf() worked. But still, I'm only able to pass 80% of the test cases for this problem!